# Unbind single keycode from a set of added keycode events

Tags: jquery, keypress

jQuery:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 27)
    {
        hide_popup();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode==13)
    {
        do_submission();
    }
});
```

At some situation, I need to unbind certain keypress codes. Say when a popup is closed, I need to unbind the keycode 27. Or if a form is submitted, I need to unbind only the keycode 13. Is there anyway to unbind certain keycodes only, since `$(document).unbind('keyup')` removes all these keycodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't unbind the entire event. Instead have a flag variable which is set by other functions to indicate whether the enter keypress should be handled. Something like this:

```
var processEnterKeyPress = true;

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        hide_popup();
    }
    else if (processEnterKeyPress && e.keyCode == 13) {
        do_submission();
    }
});

$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    processEnterKeyPress = false;
});
```

Comment: But if there are n number of codes, it will be tough to set lot of flags, right? Cannot we simplify it?

Comment: Not really. As you've seen, you can only unbind the event which will stop all key presses being handled. Using flags is a much better pattern to follow.